# how to show an arrow on mapview showing the driving direction

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I want to show an arrow image on GMSMapView(i am using google maps sdk). 
Now if i am driving(arrow is showing my current location) and i have to take left turn then i have to change bearing of mapView. But i have no idea how to do this.

I am trying to change bearing in didUpdateHeading

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{
if(newHeading.headingAccuracy>0)
{

    float heading = newHeading.magneticHeading; //in degrees
     //heading = (heading*M_PI/180);
    //NSLog(@"heading=%f", heading);
    [mapView animateToBearing:heading];
}}
```

headingFilter is set to 12.

I have also tried trueHeading, but magneticHeading is giving better results not accurate though.
Please help.

Comment: have you tried `[Your CLLocationManager instance].desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` ?

Comment: yes, locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually need to convert anything to degrees. The `newHeading` object you get from your delegate method should be enough.
The [GMS-reference for the animateToBearing:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view.html#a5e59e999c9fa8222ecc8b9b45ce95976) requires a `CLLocationDirection` as a parameter. The **newHeading.magneticHeading** or **newHeading.trueHeading** provided by the delegate method is an object of this type.
Also: you're converting the newHeading to a float, where as a `CLLocationDirection` is a double, so the GMS-function will also require a double. [See reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010238-CH2-SW8)

Comment: i am not converting it to degrees. see the code i had posted. Even [mapView animateToBearing:newHeading.magneticHeading]; is not working properly

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant radians. Just try 
    `if(newHeading.headingAccuracy>0)
    {
        [mapView animateToBearing:newHeading];
    }`

Comment: have you ever tried this ?? in animateToBearing we can pass CLLocationDirection newHeading is of type CLHeading

Comment: mapView.animate(toBearing: newHeading.magneticHeading)
- works fine